# Как сортировать средствами API по TV?

Tags: modx

Как в **Modx Revo** сортировать средствами **API** по **TV**?
Искал в документации и на просторах инета, но ничего похожего нет.
**Нужно именно через API**, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Сортировать ресурсы? По tv-шкам какого типа(цифры или символы)?

Comment: Да, ресурсы. Например по дате и/или по числу.

Answer (score 1):

Советую воспользоваться для этой задачи pdoTools - он берет на себя всю магию с хитрым приведением типов тв к нужному для сортировки формату:

```
 <?php

 $tv_name = 'integer_tv';
 $tv_type = 'integer';
 $direction = 'ASC';

 $pdo = $modx->getService('pdoFetch');
 $resources = $pdo->getCollection('modResource',
      // where
      array(
           'template' => 1,
      ),
      // config (http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/general-settings)
      array(
           'parents' => 0,
           'sortbyTV' => $tv_name,
           'sortbyTVType' => $tv_type,
           'sortdirTV' => $direction
      )
 );
 foreach ($resources as $res) {
      print $res['pagetitle']."\n";
 }
```

подробнее:

https://bezumkin.ru/training/course2/3005/

https://bezumkin.ru/training/course2/3006/

https://modx.pro/components/4931-pdotools-version-1-10-1-pl-sorting-tv-settings/

Comment: Разбираюсь с API по этому готовые варианты не интересны.

Comment: Тоесть заглянуть под капот класса https://github.com/bezumkin/pdoTools/blob/master/core/components/pdotools/model/pdotools/pdofetch.class.php и выяснить как он работает с API не инетересно? Тогда добро пожаловать в исходный код движка https://github.com/modxcms/revolution с этих пор Вы сами по себе.